# Android studio does not see setupWithNavController

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I was looking for information, there is an answer "Restart android studio" but it did not help

> Error: Unresolved reference: setupWithNavController

app:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.relesrulate"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'


    // Navigation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$navigation_version" // For Kotlin use navigation-fragment-ktx
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$navigation_version" // For Kotlin use navigation-ui-ktx

    implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.2.0'

    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.1"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3"
}
```

progect:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
    ext.room_version = '2.1.0-alpha07'
    ext.navigation_version = '2.1.0-alpha02'
    ext.kodein_version = '5.2.0'
    ext.lifecycle_version = '2.0.0'
    ext.retrofit_version = '2.5.0'


    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files



        //classpath 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.1.0-alpha02'
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.1.0-alpha02"
    } }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    } }

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir  }
```

What needs to be fixed?
And sometimes a fragment does not appear in the navigation, new ones that have been recently added

Answer (score 3):

As per the comments at the end of your navigation dependencies: `For Kotlin use navigation-fragment-ktx`, `For Kotlin use navigation-ui-ktx`. Since you're using Kotlin, you should use those to get access to Kotlin extension methods, such as `setupNavController`:

```
// Navigation
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigation_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigation_version"
```

Comment: Did not work for me with 2.3.5. I'm wondering if I'm missing something else? I'm using the Androidx toolbar but not getting `setupWithNavController`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue for adding navcontroller with toolbar, then I figured out that it was due to incorrect imports.

By mistake, I imported wrong toolbar (android.widget.toolbar), then I changed to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar and it worked fine.